# Mutate with condition on ALL other columns to add a new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

First question ever for me! Hope I make it clear and simple :D

#### Subject

I want to add a new column which content if based on a condition based on **all** other columns content.

#### Data and wanted transformation

I have the following (kinda messy) data-frame and I'm trying to add a column that should contain "Yes" if one other column contains 0 or "No" if none of the other columns contains "0".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
all_extract <- read_excel("all_extract.xlsx")
View(all_extract)                                                                                                                                 
all_extract
A tibble: 25 x 14
     tag1 `tag1 -1`  tag2 `tag2 -1`  tag3 `tag3 -1`  tag4 `tag4 -1`  tag5 `tag5 -1`  tag6 `tag6 -1`  tag7 `tag7-1`
     <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2    NA        0     NA        1     NA        2     NA         1    -1        1     NA         1     0
2     2    NA        2     NA        1     NA        2     NA         2    NA        1     NA         2     0
3     1    NA        1     NA        1     NA        2     NA         1    NA        2     NA         1     0
4     1    NA        2     NA        1     NA        2     NA         1    NA        1     NA         1     0
5     2    NA        1     NA        1     NA        2     NA         1    NA        2     NA         1     0
6     2    NA        1     NA        1     NA        2     NA         0    NA        1     NA         2     0
7     1    NA        2     NA        1     NA        2     NA         0    NA        1     NA         1     0
8     1    NA        1     NA        2     NA        2     NA         1    NA        1     NA         1     0
9     1    NA        2     NA        1     NA        2     NA         1    NA        2     NA         1     0
10    1    NA        2     NA        1     NA        2     -1         1    NA        2     NA         1     0
# … with 15 more rows
```

For replication, file can be download [with this link](https://github.com/TimotheePremat/Stack/blob/main/all_extract.xlsx).

#### Attempts and issues

I've tried to do it with `dplyr mutate`, but it works with one or several *named* columns, not with all columns; I need to write a script that I can apply to a bunch of files that have not the same number of columns. If my understanding is correct, `mutate_all` and `mutate_if` do not do what I want, as unlike `mutate` they do not add a new column but change the content of the existing one that match the criteria. Yet, they are the only thing I can find when searching for help on the internet.

For instance, I can apply `mutate` with a condition on *one* column:

```
all <- all_extract %>%
    mutate(Final_schwa = case_when(syll_tag2==0 ~ 'Schwa',
        TRUE ~ 'No schwa'))
```

I have find many solution for *multiple* columns, none for *all* columns.

I also tried to use `across` within `mutate`, but I don't know how to indicate all columns. Ideally, I thought I could use something like:

```
mutate(across(starts_with("tag"), "Yes"))
```

But I cannot managed to get the right syntax for it to work. Also, I'm not even sure `across` is supposed to be able to do what I want.

#### Summary

So: is there a way to apply *real* `mutate` (for adding a column) with a condition based on all other columns (for the new column to be filled with "Yes/No" content based on the all-columns condition)?

Thanks in advance if you could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `pivot_longer`

As Konrad has pointed out, this solution is superior to the one below because it preserves data types - if your data contains multiple types, they would be coerced into a single type by `t` which could result in data loss.

```r
new_col <- 
all_extract %>%
pivot_longer(everything()) %>% #This will make a 2-col df w/ names: (name, value)
group_by(name) %>% 
summarise(any_zero = any(value == 0))

rbind(all_extract, new_col["any_zero"])
```

### Or transpose the data and `summarise(across(everything))`

I think this solution is a little more intuitive if you're a visual thinker, but there's a risk of data loss, because `t` returns a matrix, and matrices can't contain multiple types.

```r
new_col <- 
all_extract %>%
t %>%
as_tibble %>% # (because t() returns a matrix)
summarise(across(everything(), function(x){
any(x == 0) 
})) %>%
t # transposing again will coerce our single row df into a column vector

all_extract$new_col <- new_col
```

Comment: Rather than `t` (a matrix function) I’d use `pivot_longer`. It preserves the proper data types. — and `x %in% 0` is more conventionally written as `x == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to add 'Yes' if there is atleast 1 zero in a row?

You can use `rowSums` as :

```
all_extract$new_col <- ifelse(rowSums(all_extract == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, 'yes', 'no')

#Without ifelse
all_extract$new_col <- c('No', 'Yes')[(rowSums(all_extract == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0) + 1]
```

Comment: Works just fine, and simple syntax to understand for a noobie as me! Thanks a lot Ronak!